# Access denied to http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/

Tags: hibernate, maven, jboss, annotations

I tried to add hibernate annotation to my Maven project but I had this following error :

> - ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for hibernate-commons-annotations:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:3.0.0.GA: 
>     ArtifactResolutionException: Failure to transfer hibernate-commons-annotations:hibernate-commons-annotations:pom:3.0.0.GA from http://
>     repository.jboss.com/maven2/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will >not be reattempted until the update interval of JBoss repository has elapsed 
>     or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact hibernate->commons-annotations:hibernate-commons-annotations:pom:3.0.0.GA from/to 
>     JBoss repository (http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/): Access denied to >http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/hibernate-commons-annotations/hibernate-
>     commons-annotations/3.0.0.GA/hibernate-commons-annotations-3.0.0.GA.pom. Error >code 403, Forbidden
>
>   - ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for hibernate->annotations:hibernate-annotations:jar:3.3.0.GA: 
>       ArtifactResolutionException: Failure to transfer hibernate-annotations:hibernate->annotations:pom:3.3.0.GA from http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/ was 
>       cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the >update interval of JBoss repository has elapsed or updates are forced. Original 
>       error: Could not transfer artifact hibernate-annotations:hibernate->annotations:pom:3.3.0.GA from/to JBoss repository (http://repository.jboss.com/
>       maven2/): Access denied to http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/hibernate->annotations/hibernate-annotations/3.3.0.GA/hibernate-
>       annotations-3.3.0.GA.pom. Error code 403, Forbidden

I use this code

```
<repository>
  <id>JBoss repository</id>
  <url>http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/</url>
</repository>
```

and

```
<!-- Hibernate annotation -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>hibernate-annotations</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.0.GA</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>hibernate-commons-annotations</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0.GA</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Maven Central repository instead. Have a look [here](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3a%22org.hibernate%22%20AND%20a%3a%22hibernate-annotations%22).

Answer (score 7):

According to the description of the [JBoss Maven Repositories](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/MavenRepository), 
`http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/` has been deprecated and should be replaced by `http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/`.

You can read how developers should [configure Maven to use the JBoss Repository](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/MavenGettingStarted-Developers).

So in your POM use :

```
<repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>jboss-public-repository-group</id>
    <name>JBoss Public Repository Group</name>
    <url>http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
  </repository>
</repositories>
```

For the `hibernate-annotations:hibernate-annotations:3.3.0.GA` dependency, using the Maven Central repository won't help,
because it isn't hosted by it. But it is hosted by JBoss Repository in **JBoss Deprecated**.
However you will find it (renamed) in Maven Central at `org.hibernate:hibernate-annotations:3.3.0.ga`.

If you really want to use the deprecated repository :

```
<repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>jboss-deprecated</id>
    <name>JBoss Deprecated</name>
    <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/deprecated/</url>
  </repository>
</repositories>
```

The different JBoss Maven Repositories / Groups are explained [there](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/MavenRepository).

See also :

- [How To Add Remote Repository In Maven](http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-add-remote-repository-in-maven-pom-xml/)

Concerning JBoss, the deprecated groupIds (like `hibernate-annotations`) are published [there](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/MavenJBossGroupIds).